The Nature and Durability of Bonds Formed in Constrained Environments: A Philosophical Inquiry
I've been reflecting on the nature of friendships that form in environments where individuals are brought together by circumstances beyond their usual choosing, such as addiction rehabilitation centers, support groups, or even more constrained settings like prisons. These environments are unique, often characterized by a shared, intense experience or a common goal of recovery or survival. From personal observations and experiences, it seems that bonds formed in such settings can be incredibly strong and develop rapidly, perhaps due to the vulnerability and openness that these circumstances engender.
However, this leads me to ponder several questions from a philosophical standpoint:
To what extent does the forced nature of these environments contribute to the depth and rapidity of bond formation? Is it merely the sharing of personal, often painful experiences that lays a stronger foundation for these relationships, or does the context of shared adversity play a more significant role?
Can these relationships, formed out of necessity or shared struggle, be considered as genuine and potentially lasting as those formed under more 'voluntary' circumstances? Or is there an element of desperation or situational convenience that might make them inherently more fragile or ephemeral?
In comparing different constrained environments (e.g., rehab centers vs. prisons), are there notable differences in how these relationships form or endure? Does the specific nature of the constraint or the common goal (recovery, survival, etc.) influence the quality or longevity of these bonds?
I am keen to explore these questions not just from a theoretical perspective but also in terms of practical implications for understanding human relationships and the social support mechanisms that can arise in challenging conditions. I welcome insights, experiences, and thoughts from the community on this complex topic.
Thank you for engaging with my inquiry.

you might want to add something to constrast these to friendships formed in school and work settings (school also has the peculiar factor of young age). in fact, seeing how school/work friendships form and disappear once the individuals are removed from this shared contexts may well inform you about these other contexts :)

@ac15 thanks, I am new here and am unsure of the etiquette when posting a thought. I am not a philosopher merely a mathematician.

the best philosophers are mathematicians, by accident or not ;p

It’s refreshing to see a question on something practically un-mathematizable.

@ac15 I strongly disagree with your assessment.
You mention contrasting these friendships with school friendships (which you claim do not tend to last).
I think it's the opposite. I think these are exactly the same as school friendships. All I could think while reading the OP was "what about school?" Imo school is a shared struggle. People frequently make best friends for life from school. My wife for example has 4 very strong good friendships from school life. She doesn't actually like any of them particularly, but they are bonded for life.

@ac15 I have been interested in this since it started to effect my own life and the only name that keeps popping up is Erving Goffman, but I would not know where to start and people talk about him as if I should just know his theories, are you familiar with his work and what would be a good intro? if indeed you are familiar.

hi, @PaulA, i can't be of much help since my knowledge of/exposure to sociology is essentially nil, but there are some entries about him on some of wiley's big encyclopedias/reference works:
https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/9780470999912.ch3 ; https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/9781405165518.wbeosg061.pub2 ; https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/9781118430873.est0154 ;
https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/9781444396621.ch24 ; + this short book:
https://www.taylorfrancis.com/books/mono/10.4324/9780203002346/erving-goffman-greg-smith
